# Playing a video after a video in Android's TextureView has issues

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, playback, textureview

Using a MediaPlayer inside a TextureView to play videos, it works.

When a video ends and another video should be played,  I resize the TextureView to fit the up-coming video's aspect-ratio (example - from 3:4 to 9:16 and so on..).

The problem, after the first video ends, it's last frame remains shown, 
Than the TextureView is resized, **the last frame of the first video remains for a split second but now with a bad aspect-ratio**, the second video is being played well.

Images of videos showing a (Size X Size) rectangles:

Image1:
video 1, (3:4):

[image]

Image2:
video 1, here we are between the 2 videos, video 1's last frame, after resizing it's now at (9:16), but the rectangle is looking bad. the below picture is shown for a split second:

[image]

Image3:
video 2, (9:16), playing well but after showing image2 for a split second:

[image]

There's nothing special about the code being used, here are some parts of it:

```
// To init the TextureView and MediaPlayer:

public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
    m_MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    m_Surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
    m_MediaPlayer.setSurface(m_Surface);
}

m_TextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

// To Resize:
LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(newTVWidth, newTVHeight);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
m_TextureView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

// To play:
m_MediaPlayer.reset();
m_MediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoFilePath);
m_MediaPlayer.prepare();
// <--- Here comes a call to "To Resize" which is shown right above this code
m_MediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Hi Miko Diko, did you find the solution of the above issue. I have tried everything but no success.

Comment: Put your Texture View in  same wrapper layout width and height and then setLayoutParams() in the. It does the trick. I had same issue I solve in this way. I don't know how it works but it works for me after lot of research. If need further info let me know.

Comment: Hey, I didn't understand what you meant, would you mind posting the code that shows how ?

Comment: user1154390, Would you mind explaining more ?

Comment: <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" /> </FrameLayout> After applying transform textureView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(viewWidth, viewHeight));

Comment: Miko Diko,  have u tried above solution?

Comment: Hey, The code you posted was already tried, but you said transform, then I've found https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieActivity.java which I already tried before, but now tried again --> copied adjustAspectRatio(), removed textureView.setLayoutParams() and it seems to work well (when using only transform without setLayoutParams) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options, maybe.

In theory you can clear the Surface by disconnecting the media player, clearing the surface with GLES, and then connecting the media player again.  See `clickPlayStop()` and `clearSurface()` in Grafika's [PlayMovieSurfaceActivity](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieSurfaceActivity.java).  This uses MediaCodec, not MediaPlayer, so I'm not sure how it'll translate.

Another option is to use the TextureView transform rather than a custom frame layout to set your aspect ratio.  Because your layout doesn't change, there is no flash of a distorted frame.  See `adjustAspectRatio()` in [PlayMovieActivity](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieActivity.java) for an example.